# What is the difference between reactor.run() vs reactor.runReturn() in twisted?

Tags: python, multithreading, qt4, twisted, reactor

Here is the code I was given, I am not entirely sure what is the function of runReturn, and the documentation seems a little bit sparse.

I suspect that it is the same as `reactor.run()` but give back the thread management to somewhere else?

```
    app=QtGui.QApplication('monitor GUI')  # Create the application
    app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)
    if reactor is None:  # reactor may be the module twisted.internet.reactor
        import qt4reactor  # Must be after Qt application is created
        qt4reactor.install()

        from twisted.internet import reactor

        reactor.runReturn()
```

Thanks

Comment: I just did a quick scan through the twisted internet reactor source and I didn't see a reactor.runReturn there.  Are you loading the reactor from some other location?

Comment: It's a special Qt4 reactor thing.  It's not a normal feature of reactors.

Answer (score 0):

PyQT apps have own event-loop similar(!) to twisted's reactor. Both of them blocking main loop. In another words, both of them want to control whole code flow.

'Using `qt4reactor` and `reactor.runReturn()` nails twisted to PyQt. From that point on,
Twisted behaves normally as does Qt / PyQt...  The way god intended.'